# I have a Website and an iOS App. How would I go about building an API for them to talk?

Tags: php, ios

I have a website and a native iOS App for that site. Right now, the app communicates with the site by pulling down an XML file. Im curious how I could make an API so that they could talk in a live programmic way. This would allow me to do more advanced things with the app.

I have never done anything like this before and I dont know where to start, any suggestions?

The site is written in PHP btw, not that it really matters because the API I want to make will be seperate from the existing code.

-Thanks

Comment: isn't pulling xml a live programmic way? Is the XML generated dynamically?

Comment: Best way to do it would be to build a REST API   http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/whatisrest.html

Comment: REST API would allow bi-directional communication via XML or JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that using REST APIs is an excellent approach.

Perhaps it can be illustrative to look at an interaction with a web server would look like if you were going to write your own web service, without the aid of a REST API. If you can get your head around this approach, you can then tackle this with REST APIs, perhaps better understanding what's going on behind the scenes (and appreciating what the APIs bring to the table).

For example, here is some trivial PHP that receives a JSON input from the iOS device in the form:

```
{"animal":"dog"}
```

And it will return JSON indicating the sound that that animal will make:

```
{"status":"ok","code":0,"sound":"woof"}
```

(where "`status`" is whether the request was "`ok`" or "`error`", where "`code`" is a numeric code to identify the type of error, if any, and "`sound`" is, if the request was successful, the sound that that animal makes.)

The PHP source code, `animal.php`, for this simple example might look like:

```
<?php

// get the json raw data

$handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
$http_raw_post_data = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $http_raw_post_data .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle); 

// convert it to a php array

$json_data = json_decode($http_raw_post_data, true);

// now look at the data

if (is_array($json_data))
{
    $animal = $json_data["animal"];
    if ($animal == "dog")
        $response = array("status" => "ok", "code" => 0, "sound" => "woof");
    else if ($animal == "cat")
        $response = array("status" => "ok", "code" => 0, "sound" => "meow");
    else
        $response = array("status" => "error", "code" => 1, "message" => "unknown animal type");
}
else
{
    $response = array("status" => "error", "code" => -1, "message" => "request was not valid json");
}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

The iOS code to interact with that server might look like:

```
- (IBAction)didTouchUpInsideSubmitButton:(id)sender
{
    NSError *error;

    // build a dictionary, grabbing the animal type from a text field, for example

    NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"animal" : self.animalType};
    NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:0 error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s: error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
        return;
    }

    // now create the NSURLRequest

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://insert.your.url.here.com/animal.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue:@"text/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:requestData];

    // now send the request

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:queue
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                               // now parse the results

                               // if some generic NSURLConnection error, report that and quit

                               NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
                               if (error)
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"%s: NSURLConnection error=%@", __FUNCTION__, error);
                                   return;
                               }

                               // otherwise, we'll assume we have a good response, so let's parse it

                               NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                                       options:0
                                                                                         error:&error];

                               // if we had an error parsing the results, let's report that fact and quit

                               if (error)
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"%s: JSONObjectWithData error=%@", __FUNCTION__, error);
                                   return;
                               }

                               // otherwise, let's interpret the parsed json response

                               NSString *status = results[@"status"];

                               if ([status isEqualToString:@"ok"])
                               {
                                   // if ok, grab the "sound" that animal makes and report it

                                   NSString *result = results[@"sound"];

                                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                                       self.label.text = result;
                                   });
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   // if not ok, let's report what the error was

                                   NSString *message = results[@"message"];

                                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                                       self.label.text = message;
                                   });
                               }
                           }];
}
```

Clearly, this is a trivial example (a more likely PHP server would be storing or looking up data in a database on your server), but a more complete PHP web service is beyond the scope of this iOS-specific question. But hopefully this gives you a sense of some of the building blocks for having iOS apps interact with some PHP-based web service (design an web-service interface, write the PHP to support that interface, write the iOS code to interact with that web service interface).

Comment: You are a boss. This is exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you so much for this.