# How to send array of elements from iOS to PHP webservice

Tags: php, ios, arrays

I want to send array of `<Full name, Email>` pairs to my php webservice. Should I use NSMutable array of dictionaries? What is the proper way?

Update:

I want to send in JSON.

Comment: There is no json encode function ?

Comment: I want to send array of pair of elements in JSON.

Comment: The first half [of this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968297/i-have-a-website-and-an-ios-app-how-would-i-go-about-building-an-api-for-them-t/16969767#16969767) illustrates how to send JSON from iOS to PHP web service. It's demonstrating a dictionary, but the basic technique is the same for an array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass dictionary as parameters so that your php script grabs those parameters with $_POST variable.

I will post a sample code which uses AFNetworking library.

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"key1", @"key2", nil];
NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"value1", @"value2", nil];
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: values Keys: keys];

AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL[NSURL URLWithString:@"Your  server url"];
NSURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"path" parameters:parameters];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
}];
[operation start];
```

AFNetworking class takes care of everything for you. Generally, it is better to enqueue these operations in a NSOperationQueue. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If it's going to be JSON formatted data use dictionaries. Look into AFNetworking library which handles all of your networking calls asynchronously for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this logic:

```
NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:yourDictionary/Array forKey:@"yourkeyForWebServiceFile"];
                SBJsonWriter *json=[[SBJsonWriter alloc] init];
                NSString *jsonStr = [json stringWithObject:dic];
```

now send this `jsonStr` in your `PHP` file as Post request.
I have used `SBJson` library in `this` you can use others also.